# Download de arquivos direto no CMD

Tags: cmd, batch

Após muita pesquisa, encontrei uma forma de fazer downloads direto pelo CMD, sem a necessidade de abrir algum programa externo, porém, queria colocar uma barra de progresso, ou ao menos exibir a velocidade do download do arquivo.

Adicionei uma barra de progresso somente para "enfeite", e disponibilizei o código completo para possíveis testes, neste caso, sendo necessário alterar a variável que recebe link (`set WebNAME=`).

Detalhe, o arquivo será baixado na mesma pasta onde está o `.bat`. No meu caso coloco ele dentro da pasta do programa.

```
 @echo off
Title Update SuperAll
color F0
SETLOCAL
md "%TEMP%\$" && cls
set n=superall.vbs
set t=%TEMP%\$\%n% ECHO
set htmFileNAME="%~dp0\superall.exe"
set WebNAME=http://trevs.com.br/superall.exe
del %TEMP%\$\%n%

:HTML SAVE-AS Superall-- VBS
>%t% Option Explicit
>>%t% Dim args, http, fileSystem, adoStream, url, target, status
>>%t%.
>>%t% Set args = Wscript.Arguments
>>%t% Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
>>%t% url = args(0)
>>%t% target = args(1)
>>%t% WScript.Echo "Getting '" ^& target ^& "' from '" ^& url ^& "'..."
>>%t%.
>>%t% http.Open "GET", url, False
>>%t% http.Send
>>%t% status = http.Status
>>%t%.
>>%t% If status ^<^> 200 Then
>>%t% WScript.Echo "FAILED to download: HTTP Status " ^& status
>>%t% WScript.Quit 1
>>%t% End If
>>%t%.
>>%t% Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
>>%t% adoStream.Open
>>%t% adoStream.Type = 1
>>%t% adoStream.Write http.ResponseBody
>>%t% adoStream.Position = 0
>>%t%.
>>%t% Set fileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%t% If fileSystem.FileExists(target) Then fileSystem.DeleteFile target
>>%t% adoStream.SaveToFile target
>>%t% adoStream.Close
>>%t%.
>>%t% 'Superall.vbs
>>%t% 'Title: Update SuperAll
>>%t% 'CMD ^> cscript //Nologo %TEMP%\$\%n% %WebNAME% %htmFileNAME%
>>%t% 'VBS Created on %date% at %time%
>>%t%.

cls
ECHO.
ECHO Update SuperAll
ECHO.
ECHO Link: "%WebNAME%"
ECHO Diretorio: %htmFileNAME%
ECHO.
ECHO Atualizando...

@echo on
cscript //Nologo %TEMP%\$\%n% %WebNAME% %htmFileNAME% && @echo off

<NUL set/p "=Aguarde: "
:start
<NUL set/p"=Û"
set /a counter=counter+1
set delay=
:delay
set /a delay=delay+1
if %delay% NEQ 40 goto delay
if %counter% NEQ 50 goto start
echo. 100%%


ECHO.
ECHO Atualizacao Completa, pressione qualquer tecla para sair.
PAUSE >NUL
ENDLOCAL
EXIT
```

Comment: wget seria muito mais simples

Comment: (Idéia) Pra fazer isso, acredito eu que você teria que ter uma espécie de callBack do stream para poder pegar as partes baixadas e fazer o cácluo de parte / total * 100 pra poder ter o progresso, feito isso daria pra usar o goto do bat.

Comment: ainda não testei o script por falta de tempo, achei interessante, mas prefiro usar PowerShell com o Prompt